# Java - regex - find all matches

Tags: java, regex

I need some help in Java regex.

My text is this `abc abc abc xyz xyz xyz`.
I need to find **all matches which have *only one* word between `abc` and `xyz`**

Here there are the two matches that should be returned:

1. `abc abc xyz`  ==> an `abc` is present between `abc` and `xyz`
2. `abc xyz xyz`  ==> an `xyz` is present between `abc` and `xyz`

My regex pattern:

```
abc\s+([a-z]*?)\s+xyz
```

It seems to match only the first match which is `abc abc xyz`. It does not find `abc xyz xyz`

What is the right pattern to match all?

Comment: I don't understand your expected matches.  Can you edit your question and show us what you perceive all matches to be?

Comment: I agree with Tim, it's not clear what you expect. If think you're looking for a lot more matches.

Comment: guys, please check it is very clear. actually there are 2 matches

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen, it is updated now.

Comment: as i said just one word

Comment: My answer matches your third regex too anything fault in that?

Comment: How is 'abc abc xyz' one word?

Comment: @BlackMamba, check yours here - https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html - it does not work. BTW, i did not downvote

Comment: @daniu.. what?? man read the question carefully

Comment: Your question still doesn't explain what you want or what you want is not achievable from data you've posted. abc abc abc xyz xyz xyz either produce one group containing  `abc abc xyz xyz` or ` abc abc` Nothing else is possible from this string

Comment: Got you. I reworded your question to make it more clear.

Comment: @KitKarson Do you only want to get the one word in between or the full match? Meaning `abc --- zxc` or just `---` works for you?

Comment: @AhmedAbdelhameed even just finding all in between words ll also do. in this case they are `abc` and `xyz`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you just need the one word in between and not the full match [as you stated in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51869576/java-regex-find-all-matches/51869803?noredirect=1#comment90691028_51869576), you can use a positive Lookbehind and a positive Lookahead, like this:

```
(?<=abc\s)[a-z]+(?=\sxyz)
```

Here's a [demo](https://regex101.com/r/hcv5Mo/1/).

---

If you do need the full match or you expect to have multiple spaces before/after the word, you might want to check [Andreas's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51869860/4934172).

Comment: *FYI:* This cannot handle multiple spaces between words. It also only returns the word (e.g. `abc`), not the entire match (e.g. `abc abc xyz`), as requested in the question.

Comment: @Andreas I agree with the first point. For the second point, check the comments above.

Comment: You should answer the question. If you answer a comment, you should clarify that in your answer, e.g. with a quote of and/or link to the comment.

Comment: @Andreas Done :)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you need some modifications while matching:

```
public static void main(String... args) {
    String s = "abc abc abc xyz xyz xyz";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(abc\\s+\\w+\\s+xyz)");
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    while (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group(1));
        s = s.substring(matcher.start() + 1); // ignore the just-matched and move on;
        matcher = pattern.matcher(s);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
abc abc xyz
abc xyz xyz
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that can handle multiple spaces, can tell you where the full match was found, where the words itself was found, and doesn't require resetting the `Matcher` to continue the search.

```
String input = "abc  abc  abc  xyz  xyz  xyz";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("abc(?=(\\s+([a-z]+)\\s+xyz))");
for (Matcher m = p.matcher(input); m.find(); ) {
    String match = m.group() + m.group(1);
    String word = m.group(2);
    System.out.printf("%d-%d: %s%n", m.start(), m.end(1), match);
    System.out.printf("  %d-%d: %s%n", m.start(2), m.end(2), word);
}
```

*Output*

```
5-18: abc  abc  xyz
  10-13: abc
10-23: abc  xyz  xyz
  15-18: xyz
```

It works by only matching the leading `abc` directly, then matching the rest in a zero-width positive lookahead, capturing the entire look-ahead match, so the "full" match can be built. This allows the second search result start matching with the word previously matched.

For extra bonus points, it also captured just the word itself.

You can then choose whether you want the full match, or just the word.

Answer (score -1):

You forgot delimiters and repeating the inner element. Here's an [link for online demo](https://regex101.com/r/L9f1DB/1)

```
^abc\s+(?:([a-z]*?)\s+)+?xyz$
```

And making the inner element finder less greedy